# Marshalling a P/Invoke

Tags: c#, vb.net, pinvoke

The VS code analyzer throws this warning:

> CA2101    Specify marshaling for P/Invoke string arguments    To reduce
>   security risk, marshal parameter 'buffer' as Unicode, by setting
>   DllImport.CharSet to CharSet.Unicode, or by explicitly marshaling the
>   parameter as UnmanagedType.LPWStr. If you need to marshal this string
>   as ANSI or system-dependent, specify MarshalAs explicitly, and set
>   BestFitMapping=false; for added security, also set
>   ThrowOnUnmappableChar=true.   Reg2Bat CenteredMSGBox.vb   20

Here:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Shared Function GetClassName(hWnd As IntPtr, buffer As System.Text.StringBuilder, buflen As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

I need to use the ANSI encoding but I don't understand what I need to do, so how I need to marshall this?

Comment: Why do you need to use the ANSI version?

Comment: @David Heffernan I were confussed I don't need ANSI at last

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the declaration from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetClassName.html).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetClassName(
    IntPtr hWnd, 
    StringBuilder lpClassName,
    int nMaxCount
);
```

If you (for whatever reason) wanted to import the ASCII version then it would look like

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
static extern int GetClassNameA(
    IntPtr hWnd, 
    StringBuilder lpClassName,
    int nMaxCount
);
```

Another alternative is to specify marshalling behaviour for individual parameters as in

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetClassNameA(
    IntPtr hWnd, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder lpClassName,
    int nMaxCount
);
```

Comment: Could you explain what the SetLastError attribute means?

Comment: @Recipe The documentation explains that